# EFcore LazyLoading - What is requested to the database when filtering on a child property

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I'm using lazy loading and I'm concerned about performance.

Let's say I have an object A, which contains a list of object B.

I'll retrieve the object A from the database using lazy loading. Which means the list of object B will not be retrieve if I don't access it.

But if I do something like this:

```
ObjectA.ObjectsB.Where(b => b.Id == 12);
```

Will it query all the objects B and than filters it, or will it query only the result of the expression ?

Comment: If you worry about performance, switch lazy loading off completely. Yes, it will first get everything into memory and then filter, a waste of resources

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server you can use SQL Server Profiler to see the type of query that SQL is doing.

I did the following queries:

```
        var context = new LabContextDb();
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
        var roles = user.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserId == 1).ToList();
```

My SQL produced was:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [x].[Id] FROM [AbpUsers] AS [x] WHERE [x].[Id] = CAST(1 AS bigint)

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[RoleId], [e].[UserId]
FROM [AbpUserRoles] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[UserId] = @__get_Item_0',N'@__get_Item_0 bigint',@__get_Item_0=1
```

But if I do something like this:

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserRoles.Any(y => y.Id == 1));
```

My SQL will be like this:

```
  SELECT TOP(1) [x].[Id]
  FROM [AbpUsers] AS [x]
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM [AbpUserRoles] AS [y]
  WHERE ([y].[Id] = CAST(1 AS bigint)) AND ([x].[Id] = [y].[UserId]))
```

SQL Server Profiler is a good way to see what is happening behind the scene. Another tip is to use .ToList() than if you need to iterate through big lists your statement won't be executed each time that the loop occurs since when you are using Where conditions returns an IQueryable(...).

Comment: The OP wants to retrieve the related data conditionally, while your second code is still retrieving the first object but with excessive condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after reading the answer of Flavio Francisco, I did a test myself with the SQL Profiler.

```
var objectA = (await _repo.Object.FindByCondition(obj => obj.Id == 3)).FirstOrDefault();
var objectB = objectA.ObjectsB.Where(obj => obj.Id == 1);
```

In the profiler, it first did a call to get the Object A, then, it requested all the objects B.

Filter is therefore happening at code level, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work for you.

```
var objectB = (from objA in _repo.Object join objB in ObjectsB 
               on objA.Id equals objB.ObjectAId
               where objA.Id == 3 && objB.Id == 1
               select u).ToList();
```

To avoid calling all Object B's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it as instructed in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#applying-filters-when-explicitly-loading-related-entities) document which is the same as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) document for ef core :

```
dbContext.Entry(ObjectA)
    .Collection(b => b.ObjectsB)
    .Query()
    .Where(b => b.Id == 12)
    .Load();
```

Then trace it using Sql Profiler and see that it is filtered at database level.